# Passing data among React components via exports / imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export

In React, I see recommendations to pass global type data either by passing to each component beneath it until it reaches the target component or via `Context`. I understand this is important for components reacting to data changes.

If I don't need my component to react to the data, can I just export it from the higher component into my lower components? For example, if I create a history object and exported a reference to it, I can use it in any component as long as I import it in. I've tested this and its worked. Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: Yes that's valid, there's no disadvantages in your situation. Obviously the usual issue would be if the data wasn't in state/props then your component wouldn't update when it changes, but in your case that's what you want so all good

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444 . When I don't see anyone else using it, I get suspicious if I'm wrong in some way. Very helpful.